# Determining the Galois group of a cubic without using discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Question: Suppose I want to calculate the Galois group of a cubic polynomial.  If that cubic is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we can use the discriminant to determine if the Galois group is $A_3$ or $S_3$.  That is, if the discriminant is a square, the Galois group is $A_3$, otherwise, the Galois group is $S_3$.  BUT, the discriminant of a cubic is $18abcd-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4ac^3-27a^2d^2$.  Suppose this isn't memorized and the derivation is quite tedious... how else could we approach a cubic?  In particular, I'm interested in irreducible cubics over $\mathbb{Q}$ (an example would be nice), but if you'd also like to say something about reducible cubics over $\mathbb{Q}$, that would be welcomed as well!

Thank you.

After typing this question, I see that it is asked here: [Galois group of an irreducible cubic polynomial without using the discriminant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679491/galois-group-of-an-irreducible-cubic-polynomial-without-using-the-discriminant), with an answer, but, much like the OP, I am wondering if there are "elementary methods", such that you may find in a typical course in Abstract Algebra, but may not usually be taught for whatever reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not quite basic Galois theory, but definitely a standard part of basic algebraic number theory:

Assuming we've rearranged so that the (irreducible) cubic $f(x)$ is monic and has integer coefficients, if we can find a prime $p$ such that the reduction of $f$ mod $p$ factors as linear polynomial and irreducible quadratic, then there is a $2$-cycle in the global Galois group. The irreducibility implies presence of a $3$-cycle, so there's no choice left but that the Galois group is $S_3$.

Similarly, if the cubic has exactly one real root (and two complex), we also conclude that there's a $2$-cycle in the Galois group.

The same line of thinking applies to irreducible prime degree $q$ polynomials: the irreducibility implies existence of a $q$-cycle in the Galois group. If not all roots are real, and/or if there is some prime modulo which there is an irreducible quadratic factor, then the Galois group has to be $S_q$, since any $q$-cycle and a $2$-cycle generate the whole thing.

Comment: Very neat!  +1.  I am going to hold off on accepting it as the answer to see if anyone else has any other methods, but I really like this!  Thank you!

Comment: In the last paragraph ("if not all roots are real"): So complex conjugation is one of the elements of $G$. But if there are *several* pairs of complex roots, it does not induce a (single) 2-cycle! I am not 100% sure if $S_n$ is also generated by an $n$-cycle and an *arbitrary* involution?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Only when $n$ is prime, I believe.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen,  certainly I'm claiming nothing about $S_q$ unless $q$ is prime (at least because I don't know what is true). But/and, in the case of complex conjugation, the localized version of the field (which is a product of $\mathbb R$'s and $\mathbb C$'s) does give a $2$-cycle (if there are any $\mathbb C$'s), and not just an order-two automorphism, I think. I certainly may be mistaken about this! :)

Comment: Since we're off on this tangent, note that in $S_4$, the $4$-cycle $(1234)$ and the transposition $(13)$ generate $D_4\subset S_4$. But it's easy to show that when $p$ is prime, any transposition will work.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Not even if $n$ is prime. For example if $n=5$, then a $5$-cycle and the permutation $(1,2)(3,4)$ even, so the most they can generate is $A_5$. Same for every other prime $p>5$.

Comment: @markvs, interesting point! :)